# How to post image on facebook by using selenium chrome webdriver and vba?

Tags: vba, selenium, facebook, selenium-webdriver, file-upload

I am very new to Selenium and I'm trying to create an application, which gets some information from an excel sheet, logs into a specific facebook page (not a person's profile), and creates a post which contains an image.

So far I've managed to log into the page account but I have no clue on how to upload a certain image due to the fact that it seems that the webdriver cannot interact with the filedialog that appears if I (programmatically) click on the "upload image" button. Also I cannot find any "upload" id or whatsoever.

Posting here the code I need help with:

```
' After having logged in, this creates a post

Dim ele As WebElement
Dim drv As New WebDriver

Set ele = drv.FindElementByXPath("//*[@aria-label='Crea un post']") ' This selects the "create a new post" button
ele.Click
Application.Wait (100)
If Not IsEmpty(Cells(24, 2)) Then ' Adds picture if there is one specified in the excel sheet
    Set ele = drv.FindElementByXPath("//*[@aria-label='Foto/video']") ' This clicks the "add Picture" button, but then the FileDialog appears and I cannot interact with it
    ele.Click
    ele.SendKeys "C:\mytestimage.png"
End If
Set ele = drv.FindElementByXPath("//*[@aria-label='Scrivi qualcosa a mypage']") ' Italian for "write something to mypage"
ele.SendKeys "Whatever I want to be written in the post"
```

Comment: Interacting with Facebook’s UI in such an automated fashion is against their ToS.

Comment: This is interesting, considering that there are commercial services that do the same stuff (e.g. later.com)

Comment: The might have explicit permission from Facebook, or they might actually be using the API. (Or they might simply be violating the ToS, and have not yet been caught or punished yet.)